# Using array function on an object

Tags: php

In PHP is it possible for the array functions such as `array_values()` and `array_key_exists()` to be used on an object ?

Answer (score 5):

`array_key_exists()` used to work for objects, but as of PHP 5.3.0, it doesn't anymore.  You should use `property_exists()` instead.

Comment: Or you could just use isset() which works on both -- although that will return false if the value is NULL.

Comment: @evil3 - or just roll your own using `is_array` then `array_key_exists` or `property_exists`.

Comment: `array_key_exists` still works with objects, the difference being only on static properties. `array_walk` and `array_walk_recursive` work too. See http://codepad.viper-7.com/I55G4X and http://wiki.php.net/internals/engine/objects#get_properties

Answer (score 2):

PHP objects can be cast to an array without a method call and with virtually no performance penalty, which will allow you to use any array function you like on the properties.

```
$arr = (array) $obj;
```

Using language constructs is almost always substantially faster in PHP than calling a method. `isset` is considered a language construct.

I realise this has a faint whiff of premature optimisation, but the result of running the following code in PHP 5.3 may surprise you.

```
<?php
$count = 50000;

class Pants
{
    public $mega='wad';
    public $pung=null;
}

$s = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $p = new Pants;
    $e = property_exists($p, 'mega');
    $e = property_exists($p, 'pung');
}
var_dump(microtime(true) - $s);

$s = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $p = new Pants;
    $p = get_object_vars($p);
    $e = isset($p['mega']);
    $e = isset($p['pung']);
}
var_dump(microtime(true) - $s);

$s = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $p = new Pants;
    $p = (array) $p;
    $e = isset($p['mega']);
    $e = isset($p['pung']);
}
var_dump(microtime(true) - $s);
```

Output:

```
float(0.27921605110168)
float(0.22439503669739)
float(0.092200994491577)
```

This clearly demonstrates that the best way to do these kinds of gymnastics in PHP is to rely on whichever method uses the most first-class language constructs and the fewest method calls and the best one I've found is the (array) cast.

Answer (score 0):

For the case of `array_values()`, use `get_object_vars()` to get its public properties (depends on the scope of the client code, if you want to obtain protected and private properties).

If you want something more OO, [`ReflectionObject`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionobject.php) can do quite a lot.

Comment: Sorry, I read `array_values()` as `array_keys()`. Bah. But something worth reading I hope, for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need the functionality in `array_values` and `array_keys`, you can do this: `$keys = array_keys(get_object_vars($obj))` and `$values = array_values(get_object_vars($obj))`

A better and more OO way would be to create an interface with methods for `keys` and `values`. Then implement those methods in your class to get the keys and values. Other array-like interfaces are neatly presented in [ArrayIterator](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) class.